# Python Include contents of If/else in output not just print

Tags: python, if-statement

I am not that experienced with python, but do some python coding for small jobs.  Currently I have a job that opens a log file and pulls any records that are considered errors.  This list of errors is then added as part of an email notification.  What I would like to do is either include the list or a notification that the list was empty.  I have been able to do this in the console, but don't know how to get this added as a parameter in the email.

```
if errorlist:
    print "\n".join(errorlist)
else:
    print "No Errors Found"

# Send Email 
SMTP_SERVER = {SMTP SERVER}
SMTP_PORT = {SMTP PORT}

sender = {Sender}
password = {Password}
recipient = {Recipient}
subject = "This is the subject line"
errorlist = "<br>" "\n".join(errorlist)

body = "" + errorlist + ""

headers = ["From: " + sender,
       "Subject: " + subject,
       "To: " + ", " .join(recipient),
       "MIME-Version: 1.0",
       "Content-Type: text/html"]
headers = "\r\n".join(headers)

session = smtplib.SMTP(SMTP_SERVER, SMTP_PORT)

session.ehlo()
session.starttls()
session.ehlo
session.login(sender, password)

session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
session.quit()
```

Comment: Did you try using a variable?

Answer (score 0):

```
if errorlist:
    error_string =  "\n".join(errorlist) # assign it to variable
    print (error_string) # still print it
else:
    error_string = "" # assign blank to error_string
    print ("No Errors Found") # still print "no errors found"
    .
    .
    .
    body = ""+error_string+"" # 'body = error_string' is the same though
    .
    .
    .
    session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body) # this line you could replace "body" with "error_string" because they are pretty much goign to be equivilant because of the previous comment
```

You want to assign your error string into a variable, and then use the variable later when constructing the body. Also there is more room for simplification

Answer (score 0):

The email is sent in this line:

```
session.sendmail(sender, recipient, headers + "\r\n\r\n" + body)
```

The `body` variable contains the body of your email. In order to add something into the body of the email, it should be added to the string contained by the `body` variable. Adapting the code you already have added (which successfully prints your desired result), you could replace this line:

```
body = "" + errorlist + ""
```

with this:

```
if errorlist:
    body = "\n".join(errorlist)
else:
    body = "No Errors Found"
```